How do I turn the extruded parts into a circle


So I want to create this cylinder and this is what I have so far. but I dont know how to make the part I highlighted look like a circle. I also dont know how to create the top part of the gas cylinder. help is apreciated.

If yoi mean that you want to round the edges you can bevel them?

I tried that but it doesnt look good

You can create an edge loop then bevel it:

Scale the central edge loop:

Bevel it:

Or if you began with this shape, select these vertices:

And bevel:

